# change json value's datatype in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a JSON object with following values:

```
var json = [{
  "Time": "2017-08-17 16:35:28.000",
  "Value": "3.85"
}, {
  "Time": "2017-08-17 17:36:28.000",
  "Value": "3.85"
}, {
  "Time": "2017-08-17 18:35:28.000",
  "Value": "3.86"
}, {
  "Time": "2017-08-17 19:35:28.000",
  "Value": "3.86"
}, {
  "Time": "2017-08-18 07:35:28.000",
  "Value": "3.87"
}, {
  "Time": "2017-08-18 18:35:28.000",
  "Value": "3.86"
}];
```

The Time is in string format and I would like to change it to datetime.(Im storing them in x and y which I'm using for Highcharts)
I have used the following function:

```
json.forEach(function(element, index) {
  element.x = new Date(element['Time']).getTime();
  element.y = +element['Value'];

  delete element['Time'];
  delete element['Value'];
});
```

I am getting an error : json.forEach is not a function

Output Images:
In the Developer tools sources tab:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckfaU.png)

In the alert:
[Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyJ8I.png)

As you can see, in the developer tools, it has quotes, whereas in alert it doesn't. Don't know what the issue is

PS: Sorry i don't have enough reputation to embed the images directly

Comment: remove **quotes** from var json declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a typo, remove quotes from json declaration and your solution will work

```js
    var json = '[{  "Time": "2017-08-17 16:35:28.000",  "Value": "3.85"}, {"Time": "2017-08-17 17:36:28.000","Value": "3.85"}, {"Time": "2017-08-17 18:35:28.000","Value": "3.86"}, {"Time": "2017-08-17 19:35:28.000","Value": "3.86"}, {"Time": "2017-08-18 07:35:28.000","Value": "3.87"}, { "Time": "2017-08-18 18:35:28.000", "Value": "3.86"}]';
    
json = JSON.parse(json);
    json.forEach(function(element, index) {
      element.x = new Date(element['Time']).getTime();
      element.y = +element['Value'];

      delete element['Time'];
      delete element['Value'];
    });
 console.log(json);
```

Comment: saving the world :)

Comment: I removed the quotes. Yet im getting the same error :(

Comment: No, you're not (should not). The code works fine now. I just checked.

Comment: Note: Im passing the JSON object(after parsing) from controller. When I see the developer tools source tab, the JSON output is "[{..},{..}..]";(enclosed in quotes) whereas in alert(json), the output is [{..},{..}..];

Comment: I'll add the images :)

Comment: @anurag if you are getting variable json as `String` than try `json = JSON.parse(json);` before calling forEach

Comment: Okay ill give it a try :)

Comment: @anurag updated code snippet based on your input, hope it was helpful

Comment: Yep. Even though in the alert it was displaying it as a JSON object. It turned out to be a JSON string all along. parsing solved the issue. Thanks a ton @Nemani and Marcin for helping me out.